# Does iwlwifi drive support mesh networking?

Tags: networking, iwlwifi

There is a confusion for this driver support as [the kernel wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers) says it does not support mesh, but [the Gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Iwlwifi) says, i can enable the mesh networking:

From my part, I have installed batman-adv in these iwlwifi driver ports in 3 PCs. I can discover all the 3 pcs with `batctl o` command.

However if I give a specific IP address to `bat0` (`ip addr add 10.10.12.1/24 dev bat0`) i cannot ping the IP address from other PC. However IP address assigned by avahi-autoipd bato works.

I have 2 questions:

1. Does iwlwifi driver support mesh networking?
2. How does IP address assigned by avahi work but manual IP address allocation does not?

Comment: 1: no. See https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers

Comment: @Rinzwind: thanks for the response, i checked that link, but https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Iwlwifi link says I can enable the mesh networking on iwlwifi, thats where the confusion arises.
+ i am able to run batman-adv on them but not able to ping the ip addresses.

Comment: Ok Great, I thought its preference list which user can enable/disable feature in the driver. Thanks for clarifying.
But its strange that I can see the devices when I run batman-adv over these drivers.

Comment: `iw list` shows supported options. This looks promissing: https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/iwlwifi-next/+/5fe231e873729fa2f57cdc417d5c1f80871e2d7d/net/wireless/mesh.c but no idea if you can load a `iwlwifi-next`

Comment: since batman-adv is working, I am not sure if the driver has the *-next version or not.
Thats why I started my question with the "confusion" word. :)